# Docker + Postgres Can't Get Configuration Working

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm just getting started with docker and I can't get my API to connect to my database. I get a `connection refused`.

I'm getting this in the logs, which seems to imply the environment variables aren't being passed in: `The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".`

Also, `docker exec -ti [container_id] psql -U postgres` works, however `docker exec -ti [container_id] psql -U docker` -> `role "docker" does not exist`

I've also tried `COPY`ing an init.sql file in the Database's `Dockerfile`, but it didn't seem to have any effect.

This is my `docker-compose.yaml`. Is there anything that stands out as wrong?

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    build: ./db
    volumes:
      - ./db/pgdata:/pgdata
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=docker
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=docker
      - POSTGRES_DB=xx
      - PGDATA=/pgdata

  api:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        app_env: ${APP_ENV}
    volumes:
      - .:/go/src/github.com/x/xx
    ports:
      - "5000:8080"
    links:
      - db
```

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM golang
ARG app_env
ENV APP_ENV $app_env

# Copy the local package files to the container's workspace
COPY . /go/src/github.com/x/xx
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/x/xx

# added vendor services will need to be included here
RUN go build

# if dev setting will use pilu/fresh for code reloading via docker-compose volume sharing with local machine
# if production setting will build binary
CMD if [ ${APP_ENV} = production ]; \
    then \
    api; \
    else \
    go get github.com/pilu/fresh && \
    fresh -c recompile.conf; \
    fi

# Document that the container uses port 8080
EXPOSE 8080
```

And this is my Dockerfile under ./db

```
FROM postgres:latest
EXPOSE 5432
```

Comment: What name do you use to contact your DB from your API ?

Comment: Why are you mounting a local folder to your docker container as pgdata? Do you just need to persist the data?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running windows this can not work.
See this [issue](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/445).

Alternatively you can use a named volume like this:

```
postgresql:
  image: ./db
  volumes:
  - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  postgres:
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see it seems like a network issue. It's difficult to debug your files without the full scope, so here is the [doc about the internal networks](https://docs.docker.com/network/) and how to allow connections between containers.

Also, here is a full working `docker-compose.yml` with a Postgres database and a bridge linked network :

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:11-alpine
    network_mode: bridge
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=whatever"

  clientApp:
    container_name: cinema
    image: your/image:latest
    network_mode: bridge
    external_links:
      - postgres
```